# What is the node.js and its purpose?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay noob question.

1. What is node.js?
2. What is its purpose and where is it used?

They say that it is a server-side technology used to perform parallel operations. Google V8 is the parser and the language is Javascript but I thought that Javascript does not work on server-side. How exactly does node.js do this?

Sorry I tried to look up a good answer for it but I couldn't find any good explanation of node.js. I don't quite get what node.js does from these posts either:

1. [What is Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js)
2. [What is node.js based on, under the hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022541/what-is-node-js-based-on-under-the-hood)

Comment: *"I thought that Javascript does not work on server-side"* Well, you are wrong in that case. What made you think that?

Comment: I didn't understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js so I thought I would create another question hoping that someone would help me understand what node.js is? I wrote that in the lower part of my question.

Comment: Not sure what is there to understand - JavaScript is a language, just like PHP, Java, Ruby, etc. Node.js is a runtime environment that uses JavaScript as a language and provides the developer with tools necessary to interact with the world - access to filesystem, environment, TCP/UDP communications etc.

Comment: Node.js is V8 + I/O + a standard library... not sure what exactly you want to know.

Comment: For a browser guy/gal, I think the most important revelation of the day should be that JavaScript is a language (the syntax) and what browsers give you is the DOM, your browser's runtime environment. These, however, are two completely separate things.

Comment: @RobertRossmann okay that explanation was a bit helpful. It's just a technology used by google servers to run concurrent processes then? are these processes the requests made to the server or the applications run on the server?

Comment: Node.js has nothing to do with Google. The V8 engine is open source. It could as well use Mozilla's Spidermonkey engine.

Comment: I probably overthought the concept of node.js. seems like it allows people to write webs servers and how it handles data. @FelixKling thanks for pointing out that javascript could be used on servers. I was confused before since I had read somewhere that javascript cannot be used to interact with servers, so I thought that it couldn't be used on servers either.

Comment: There are limitations how JavaScript executed in a *browser* can communicate with other servers. However, those are restrictions imposed by the browser environment and the API it provides, for security reasons.

Comment: i guessed as much. otherwise scripts could be written to interfere with the servers on the client side.

Comment: They can be. That's why security, validation, and the like exist. Client-side JS is strict about how it can interact with the client it's running on, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Node.js is a platform for the JavaScript language that is centered around asynchronous network programming. It contains a set of libraries to help you develop server-side applications with JavaScript
2. Under the hood, Node.js is running on V8, a JavaScript engine developed by Google.

Hope this helps.

Comment: okay. Since it contains libraries, its like jquery but for developing server-side applications.